# Is it possible too evaluate $\int_0^1 \tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\tanh^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x}{1+\tanh^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x}\right]\frac{dx}{x}$? Or numerical result?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-map

Motivation for the problem [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154913/a-hard-integral-identity-on-mathse):

Is it possible to evaluate
$$
\int_0^1 \tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\tanh^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x}{1+\tanh^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x}\right]\frac{dx}{x}?
$$
Or numerical value? I attempted to use Wolfram Alpha, but I didn't receive any results.

To simplify the integral let's denote $u = \tanh^{-1}(x)$ and $v= \tan^{-1}(x)$.

Rewrite the expression using $u$ and $v$:
$$
\int_0^1 \tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\tanh^{-1}x - \tan^{-1}x}{1 + \tanh^{-1}x - \tan^{-1}x}\right] \frac{dx}{x} 
= \int_0^1 \tan^{-1}\left[\frac{u - v}{1 + u - v}\right] \frac{dx}{x}
$$

I need a numerical result or a closed form since I don't have CAS or any software.

Comment: Very likely the same method used in the mathoverflow answer (posted on arXiv) would be useful here. Changing the $\pi$ out for $1$ likely will result in a more complicated answer, though.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you, for your response. However, there seems to be a misunderstanding. I'm looking for the closed form or numerical value of the integral using Mathematica or any other CAS

Comment: @PaulSinclair Perhaps you didn't read my reply. I mentioned that I don't have Mathematica or any other Computer Algebra System (CAS), and Wolfram is unable to process it.

Comment: The method I suggested requires only pencil, paper, and a willingness to attempt it.

Comment: You can use [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vzaipbct7k) or  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=NIntegrate%5Batan%28%28atanh%28x%29-atan%28x%29%29%2F%281%2Batanh%28x%29-atan%28x%29%29%29%2Fx%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D). Maybe substituting $\tanh^{-1}(x)-\tan^{-1}(x)=y$ and expanding $x=f(y),\frac1{f(y)}$ as a series could work.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash I don’t know why but wolfram alpha is not opening and can you try Mathematica?

Comment: @Sbsty The Wolfram Alpha link works on this account’s side. However, here is the Mathematica/Wolfram Cloud [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL4KN.jpg)

Comment: $0.19496613867207875752028210370673662702276996914126\cdots$

Comment: Would a series expansion help? Also, you could try asking on MathOverflow

Comment: @ТymaGaidash can you upload behalf of me?

Comment: @Sbsty You cannot upload the problem to MathOverflow?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash I can upload it, but since you have a higher reputation and can provide better context(because I don’t know too much English)  the question might receive better answers However I'll wait to see if someone posts it on MO If no one does then I'll upload it myself

Comment: You can also get a quick numerical result on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4pou69o9ja), by the way.

Comment: Why the downvotes? There would have been an answer showing the integral equals the imaginary part of [this sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O94c.jpg) after expanding $f^{-1}(x)$ as a series to evaluate $\text{Im}\int_0^\infty \ln(1+(1+i)x)d\ln(f^{-1}(x)),f(x)=\tanh^{-1}(x)-\tan^{-1}(x)$. The integral requires more working precision for more terms as the series converges more slowly near $x=0$, but $f^{-1}(x)$’s does not diverge near it.